# How to know if UIWebView has a delegate

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

I want to add my own delegate for `UIWebView` to implement `webViewDidFinishLoad`, but at first I need to check if it already has a delegate. How I can check that?

Comment: `if (webView.delegate != nil)`, seriously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try :

```
if(myWebview.delegate != nil)
```